# How can I logoff a specific user in a Devise powered Rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session, cookies, devise

By default, the mechanism in Rails seems to be setting a session cookie, to keep track if a user's logged in or not. While this would ensure that a user is logged off when he closes the browser, I also need him to be logged of in case of inactivity. I have the following use case:

- user is logged in
- he is on a specific page ( websockets powered, no refresh )
- client pings server, in order to let the server know he's still active
- in case more than X number of minutes go by without any sign of activity, the user should be logged off

How can such a user case be handled? I thought about setting an expiration time of a few minutes on the cookie. I'd like it that the cookie's expiration time is set back to the original duration, every time the client pings the server.

I'm open to any ideas on how this problem could be tackled.

Comment: Use the module Timeoutable. Read something about it in the doc : https://github.com/plataformatec/devise

Comment: @ThomasRuiz: imho that should be the answer, not just a comment.

Answer (score 1):

If you use devise it's already there and you can configure timeout duration in devise.rb https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/lib/generators/templates/devise.rb#L132

Answer (score 1):

Use the module Timeoutable. Read something about it in the doc : http://github.com/plataformatec/devise.

**Info: migrated comment to answer.**